# Change img path based on width of screen

Tags: html, css, image, media, responsive

I have an html line:

```
<img alt="Slider Background" class="background-image" src="img/slide1.jpg" />
```

Is there any way to call a different img path when the screen is <400px?

This is a part of a slider and I would rather avoid getting into css. 
I believe there should be an easy solution right inside html – like srcset, which doesn't work for some reason:

```
<img src="img/slide1mini.jpg" srcset="img/slide1.jpg 400w"/>
```

I also tried data-media attribute with `<img>`, but no luck:

```
<img src="img/slide1mini.jpg" data-media="(max-width: 400px)" />
<img src="img/slide1.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 401px)" />
```

Community help needed badly.

Comment: Why not use the proper element?  `<input type="range" />`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this [Live FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/jo26n290/1/)

[.img-responsive is custom class in
 bootstrap]
 You can use custom class like for your site.

```
.img-responsive {
 display: block; 
 min-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
   }
```

//which you place in your html part like this

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="demo.jpg"/>
```

for background image you can just change  height: 100vh !important; and width:100%; here is back-ground image example

```css
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<img alt="Slider Background" class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGZQ54YTm4Te6RYbyrhYzs-FusS0HjKwpp8GlhpoH67XRHP6Js" />
```

Comment: He mentioned he needs to use different images right?

Comment: but using this he don't need @media query ,  this will work like auto responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think would be to use `background-image` instead of `<img>` tag, which you can modify using media queries.

For example,

```
<div class="img"></div>

.img{
background-image:url('//your link')
}
```

Now you can use media queries to change the image. For example:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
   .img{
        //change image url
     }


}
```

You can read more about media queries [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

Add two imgs to the page with appropriate classes, use css media queries to hide and show the relevant. The images with display none will not be loaded on the initial page load.

Example:

HTML:

CSS:
    .desktop { display: block; }
    .mobile { display: none; }

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px){
    .desktop { display: none; }
    .mobile { display: block; }
}
```